# WindowsApps Broken

Tags: windows

I recently tried to gain access to WindowsApps using a command i found online (very bad idea i know)
and now none of the apps inside WindowsApps works! please help!!!

this is the command I used on an admin shell that broke everything : cacls WindowsApps /t /g everyone:f /c

following this tutorial : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-cant-get-permissions-for-the-windowsapps-folder/2351e10d-31b5-4d9d-85c6-7175a82dd94e

can someone please help me restore my pc (using windows 10)?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I talked with microsoft tech team and the solution is quite simple simply type this command in an admin shell:

```
                   icacls "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" /q /c /t /reset
```

I'll leave this here in case someone else has the same problem!